# Django repeated forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a form with a dropdown select option with possible options of 1,2,3,4 or 5. Based on the user select option 'x', I render same form repeated 'x' many times. Upon submit, I try to fetch the data using following in my view

```
userprofileForm(request.POST)
```

but this fetches just the last entry or most recent entry and not all the 'x' entries.

Here is the rough HTML for my rendered form. In this instance the user selects option 2 so the form has a div repeated 2 times.

```
<form ... >
    <div>
        <label...>
        <input...>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label...>
        <input...>
    </div>
</form>
```

Upon hitting submit button, the view for registeration is triggered and like I explained above in the beggining doing

```
userprofileForm(request.POST)
```

does not fetch both the 2 entries but just the last one.

How can this be fixed so I have all form data of both the divs and how do I access it?

Comment: More information is needed. Please share your template and the respective view.

Comment: You are looking for *formsets*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I assume that the problem is with the form field which you're just replicating without changing it's name. Try making the name attribute dynamic like `<input name='1' ../>` `<input name='2' ../>` and see if it solves the problem. If your problem is different, please add the code of your view and template to the question.